# Sqoop - Hive import using Oozie failed

Tags: hadoop, import, hive, sqoop, oozie

I am trying to execute a sqoop import from oracle to hive, but the job fails with error

`WARN  [main] conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:initialize(2472)) - HiveConf of name hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join.noconditionaltask does not exist 
Intercepting System.exit(1)
<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<< 
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1] 
Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully`

1. I have all the jar files in place
2. hive-site.xml is also in place with hive metastore configuration

`<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name> 
  <value>thrift://sv2lxgsed01.xxxx.com:9083</value> 
</property>`

- I am able to run a sqoop import(using oozie) to HDFS successfully.
- I am also able to execute a hive script(using oozie) successfully
- I can also execute sqoop-hive import from commandline , but the same
  command fails when I execute it using oozie

My workflow.xml is as below

---

`<workflow-app name="WorkflowWithSqoopAction" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
        <start to="sqoopAction"/>
        <action name="sqoopAction">
                <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
                        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                        <command>import --connect
     jdbc:oracle:thin:@//sv2axcrmdbdi301.xxx.com:1521/DI3CRM --username xxxxxxx --password xxxxxx--table SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT --hive-table eg.EQX_EG_CRM_S_ORG_EXT --hive-import -m1</command>
                        <file>/user/oozie/oozieProject/workflowSqoopAction/hive-site.xml</file>
                </sqoop>
                <ok to="end"/>
                <error to="killJob"/>
        </action>
        <kill name="killJob">
            <message>"Killed job due to error: ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}"</message>
        </kill>
        <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>`

I can also find the data being loaded in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things

1) Copy hive-site.xml in the oozie workflow directory 2) In your Hive action tell oozie that use my hive-site.xml

Comment: Thanks Siva, the issue was with missing jar in /user/oozie/share/lib